# Has Facebook changed the API so we have to recreate our access token?

Tags: facebook, token

Our the publication of our application on Facebook has stopped working.  We have not changed the token, Facebook passwords, or anything else.  If we recreate the token, everything works correctly.

Has Facebook changed the Facebook API so that we have to recreate the token again?  What else could be the problem?

Comment: Sounds like something change on the Facebook's side.

Comment: What platform are you using? And what SDK are you using(if internet)? Be abit more specific so we can help you look :) They should have changelogs of every SDK, so it shouldn't be too hard to find.

Comment: What error message did you get? Did you change the app secret? Any chance the user whose token you were using changed their password, had their account locked?